# Scala error: type arguments do not conform to class type parameter bounds

Tags: scala

See the following function definition:

```
class Entity[T](
               val pi : T => String,
               val si : T => Map[Symbol,String],
               val tag : ClassTag[T],
               val address: T=>AnyRef
) {
      // some other definitions here ... 
      def filterEntity(attribute: DiscreteAttribute[T], value: String ):Unit={
         // nothing 
      }

}
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

```
/Users/i-danielk/ideaProjects/saul/src/main/scala/edu/illinois/cs/cogcomp/lfs/data_model/entity/Entity.scala:67: type arguments [T] do not conform to class DiscreteAttribute's type parameter bounds [T <: AnyRef]
[error]   def filterEntity(attribute: DiscreteAttribute[T], value: String ):Entity[T]={
```

And here is the definition of the `DiscreteAttribute`:

```
case class DiscreteAttribute[T <: AnyRef](
                                 val name : String,
                                 val mapping: T => String,
                                 val range : Option[List[String]]
                                 )(implicit val tag : ClassTag[T]) extends TypedAttribute[T,String]{
....
}
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Update: The following does not work either:

```
def filterEntity(attribute: DiscreteAttribute[T <: AnyRef], value: String ):Entity[T]={
```

Here is the error:

```
 /Users/i-danielk/ideaProjects/saul/src/main/scala/edu/illinois/cs/cogcomp/lfs/data_model/entity/Entity.scala:67: ']' expected but '<:' found.
[error]   def filterEntity(attribute: DiscreteAttribute[T <: AnyRef], value: String ):Entity[T]={
```

Update2: here is how it's been used:

```
   val filteredConstituent= EdisonDataModel.constituents.filterEntity(EdisonDataModel.Eview,"Token")
```

where

```
object EdisonDataModel extends DataModel {
  val Eview = discreteAttributeOf[Constituent]('CviewName){
    x=>x.getViewName
}
```

and

```
  def discreteAttributeOf[T <: AnyRef](name : Symbol)(f : T => String)(implicit tag : ClassTag[T]) : DiscreteAttribute[T] = {
   new DiscreteAttribute[T](name.toString,f,None)
  }
```

Update 3: 
The same error holds for the following function definition:

```
  def filterEntity(attribute: DiscreteAttribute[T], value: String ):Unit={
      // empty 
  }
```

Comment: Where does the `T` in `filterEntity` come from?

Comment: Your code sample here is incomplete. Post the defining environment of filterEntity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define a restriction for the T type that is affecting the filterEntity method.

e.g. `class Something[T <: AnyRef]` so that it matches the restriction on DiscreteAttribute

In your case you want to have the declaration of `Entity` as: `class Entity[T <: AnyRef]`.

Comment: See this does not work either:  `def filterEntity(attribute: DiscreteAttribute[T <: AnyRef], value: String ):Entity[T]={ `

Comment: You need to change it not in the usage but the definition. See comments on the question saying that your example is incomplete.

Comment: I completed the definition of the function (the first code). Any idea?

Comment: But where is the type T coming from? I'm guessing the class that contains the filterEntity method is defined.